# PHP DateTime conversion

Tags: php, datetime

I currently have stored *DateTime* in the database as follows `20130208110000` so I need to break it into 2 parts which is date in this format `08/02/2013` and time in this format `11:00 AM`, which function does this effectively?

This is the function I used to join both date and time together

```
$startMonth = $this->_getParam('starts_month_day_year');
$startTime = $this->_getParam('starts_time');
date("YmdHis",strtotime($startMonth.$startTime));
```

Comment: why dont use store the date in one of the db date\time field types and make life a lot esier

Comment: @Dagon hi its too late for modification as i planning to do changes on later time

Comment: its never to late to do things properly, you could convert then with a script in about 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
      $originalDate = "20130208110000";
      $newDate = date("d-m-Y g:i A", strtotime($originalDate));
      echo $newDate;  //08-02-2013 11:00 AM
?>
```

where,

> **g** :12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros [0 through 12]
>
> **i** :Minutes with leading zeros [00 through 59]
>
> **A**:Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem [AM or PM]

Answer (score 1):

What would be wrong with just using what you're already doing?

```
$myDate = "20130208110000";
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($myDate)); // Date, e.g. 08/02/2013
date("h:i A", strtotime($myDate)); // Time, e.g. 11:00 AM
```